# stack overflow in windows when running gdb

Tags: c, gdb, stack-overflow

I think I am experiencing a stack overflow issue when running my unit-tests through gdb within emacs on Windows.

I run exactly the same unit-tests on linux with no problems

I am also aware that I am using a horrendously memory inefficient stack-based .ini file parser within these unit-tests so it would seem to be a reasonable possibility that stack overflow is occuring.

I have noticed a few unit tests faling on Windows that passed on Linux. Further investigation reveals a (stack-based) counter in a for loop resetting itself to zero at random points in the for loops execution and the (stack-based) values in the arrays that the for loop is inspecting change for the same index value

I noticed that gdb seems to be allocated its own thread of execution under Windows - is there any way of finding out how much stack space the thread is allocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the differences between Linux and Windows is that on Windows the stack-size has to be set at compile-time (there are two sizes, initial and a predefined reserved limit).  Not sure what the default is with the compiler you are using, but you might try to increase it using --stack parameter (gcc).

On Linux the stack-size is dynamic up to the limits, generally set by the sysadmin.

Comment: using mingw from within emacs so that should work - i'll give it a go. out of interest how could you find out what the default value of --stack parameter is?

Comment: I guess that is RTFM for gcc.  For Visual Studio the initial limit is 4KB and the reserved limit is 1MB, if I had to guess then gcc is probably similar.

Comment: haha RTFM always the last resort - 4KB seems surprisingly small for MSVC

Comment: RTFM meaning "Read The Fine Manual", of course.  Yes, 4KB is small, and these limits are the same for the default process heap as well.

Comment: On 32-bit machines, no, it is only 1MB.  Yes, I have had occasion to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

Well then, perhaps Windows has tighter restrictions on the maximum amount of stack per process than Linux does?

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  details how to debug a stack overflow in Windows. It's not based on gdb, but perhaps you can still infer something.

Comment: is there any user control on the amount of stack allocated by gdb, or just running an exe from the cmd line for that matter?